# Removing object from non empty NSMutableArray causes occasional crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSMutableArray (properly initialized) that acts as buffer adding an object and deleting the first one. I works fine in most cases and always when I test it, but I very occasionally get a crash report from my users saying e.g.

```
[__NSArrayM removeObjectsInRange:]: range {0, 1} extends beyond bounds for empty array'
```

The relevant code in the app looks like this

```
[self.peakArray addObject:@(peak)];
if([self.peakArray count]>0){
    [self.peakArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

The code is in a CaptureOutput: didOutputSampleBuffer in an AVCaptureSession that is on a serial dispatch queue. The array is not iterated on or updated anywhere else. How can it crash at the remove object line? If the count is zero that line should not be executed?

(note: the array normally contains more than a hundred objects when reaching this part of the code)

Comment: does this code execute on multiple concurrent threads?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not doing a remove, while iterating on it?

Comment: I think having a check here will be better. If it's running in concurrent threads, then I believe the crash report should be something different

Comment: It's tell you array is empty. [NSMutableArray array] before you addObject

Comment: Try printing the count of the array just before `removeObject` to check how many objects (if any) there are. If there are none, then check where you are inserting, if the object is getting inserted, or being set to nil anywhere

Comment: is this code being run in an asynchronous dispatch queue?

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have updated the question.

Comment: The issue is simple - when you are doing the check, the array is not empty. When you are removing the first item, the array is empty. That can happen only when the array is updated simultaneously from multiple threads. Add logging and you will probably see the issue quickly.